# encodeUriSegment is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

Angular returns to console error

> `encodeUriSegment is not a function`

it's happen when I tried call get function from angular-resource in my own controller. It's look like angular-resource can't find this one function, but it exist in angular.js file. I installed angular-resource by bower. I have everyone file path which i need in index.html.

full error message:

```
angular.js:13920 TypeError: [horoskopy_App Error] encodeUriSegment is not a function
    at http://localhost:3000/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js:573:30
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's likely that you have a version conflict in your source.  I had the same issue and found that I was using angular-resource 1.5.9 and angular 1.6. Once I had both on the same version release the issue resolved.

Comment: Thanks for an awesome answer!!